# What is a "paying gig"?

Tags: meaning

I was invited to do a project for someone, and she mentioned "*Obviously this is a paying gig.*"

What exactly would this mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is an informal phrase to refer to a job that will pay money. Originally, a *gig* was an informal term for an engagement to play by a musician, and it has since extended to apply to any job.

Comment: Plus one for hep-cats!

Comment: With the implication that it is a small job where you might fear that it would be considered a “favor” or where the payment might be booze or drugs or room and board while the job was being done.